# Displaying correct answer for PHP quiz game

Tags: php

I am creating my first PHP script that tests the user on cranial nerve association; specifically the name of the cranial nerve is displayed to the user and they are supposed to click on the correct number corresponding to the name of the cranial nerve.

I will post my code first and my question after:

```
<?php

$generated_nerve_number = mt_rand(1,12);
switch($generated_nerve_number) {
    case '1':
        echo "Olfactory";
        break;

    case '2':
        echo "Optic";
        break;

    case '3':
        echo "Oculomotor";
        break;

    case '4':
        echo "Trochlear";
        break;

    case '5':
        echo "Trigeminal";
        break;

    case '6':
        echo "Abducens";
        break;

    case '7':
        echo "Facial";
        break;

    case '8':
        echo "Vestibulocochlear";
        break;

    case '9':
        echo "Glossopharyngeal";
        break;

    case '10':
        echo "Vagus";
        break;

    case '11':
        echo "Accessory";
        break;

    case '12':
        echo "Hypoglossal";
        break;
}


?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cranial Nerves Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Select the cranial nerve number below associated with the name of the cranial nerve given above:</p>
    <form action="cranial.php" method="POST">
        <?php
            echo "Cranial Number: ";
            for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"nerve_$i\" class=\"nerve_number\" value=\"$i\">";
            }

        ?>

        <?php
                $submit = (isset($_POST['nerve_' . $i])) ? $_POST['nerve_' . $i] : NULL;
                if($submit) {
                    $selected_nerve_number = $_POST['nerve_' . $i];
                    if($generated_nerve_number == $selected_nerve_number) {
                        echo "That is correct!";
                    } else {
                        echo "Sorry that is incorrect.";
                    }
                }
        ?>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

A quick overview of my thought process: I am randomly generating a number between 1-12 and using that number in a switch statement to echo the name of the cranial nerve. I used a for loop to generate submit buttons with names that contain the number of the cranial nerve corresponding to its displayed value. Lastly, my plan on checking whether the answer is correct or not is to use an if statement comparing the randomly generated number to the number selected and, if this is true, output a message saying that they were correct.

This is where the problem comes in: when I click any of the buttons, whether its the correct answer or not, the page just refreshes without giving any feedback on whether the answer was right or wrong. Can someone please point out the flaw?

Additionally, if there is a more optimal way of doing something in this script please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You creating 12 input[type=submit]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight problem with this approach. Your script is actually having two steps to consider: first, sending a page to the client with a randomly chosen cranial nerve, then comparing a choice with what was randomly specified.

If you wish your script to do this, you must add some logic so that it will know it have to react differently.

```
if (isset($_POST))
 {/*compare the user choice with what you had sent. 
  you will have to do add an input to your form containing the random value AND the chosen value, or you eon't be able to compare them*/}
```

currently, you're trying to do all this at once, eg, you're comparing the return value of your user before you even receive it in your post! Understand that once sent to the client (browser) your page is not linked anymore to the php. So here:

```
if($generated_nerve_number == $selected_nerve_number) {
```

you're actually comparing the random number you just generated, with the answer you will have from your user in the FUTURE, since he has not even seen it on screen yet :)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Such a simple mistake. Out of curiosity, if I were to check the users answer on a separate PHP file, but wanted to send them back to the game to continue could I just use a header("Location: cranial.php")? Or is there a better way to do this? Lastly, in a real HTML form you would have only 1 submit button. In a game like this, would you want to use 12 different buttons like I did? Or would you rather make a drop down list with numbers 1-12 and only one submit button? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could send the answer to the client in a hidden input (type="hidden") and verify with javascript the user-selected answer against the value in your input. Google AJAX and jQuery, those are powerful tools which will probably be useful in the future. Otherwise I'm a programmer, not a designer, so I wouldn't recommend you a way or another.. If you find it's ugly, it probably is, and if not it's probably ok.